# How hide a group of buttons on the homepage? vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am not able to hide a button-group on the home-page.

Hide when you click on the button moveTo(0) or scroll to top

```
  show: function() {
    this.scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset
    : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
  }
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Yevhenii/3jahek6u/3)

Comment: you want to hide buttons on "HOME" rt?

Comment: Kumar_14,  Yes. Exactly.

Answer (score 0):

So then just do this `v-if="index !== 0"` example:

```
    <div class="button-group" v-if="index !== 0">
         <button type="button" :class="{active:index ==0}" @click="moveTo(0)">home</button>
         <button type="button" :class="{active:index ==1}" @click="moveTo(1)">about</button>
         <button type="button" :class="{active:index ==2}" @click="moveTo(2)">contacts</button>
    </div>
```

This will do the trick